# Range_error at memory location 0x000000158F2FF408

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

Doing my home exercise and stock with memory location error, the code looks fine, why it doesn't work?
Could you please help me, really don't get why it comes out of range.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

double num;
double sumV;
double maxV;
double minV;
double avrV;

double vectorSum(vector<double> v) {

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        sumV = sumV + v[i];
    }
    return sumV;
}
double vectorMax(vector<double> v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    maxV = v[0];
    return maxV;
}
double vectorMin(vector<double> v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    minV = v[v.size()];
    return minV;
}
double vectorAvr(vector<double> v) {
    avrV = vectorSum(v) / v.size();
    return avrV;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> dif;
    cout << "Enter values of distance between two cities: " << endl;
    while (cin >> num) dif.push_back(num);
    cout << "Sum of your distances is: " << vectorSum(dif) << endl << "Minimum distance is: " << vectorMin(dif) << endl
        << "Maximum of your distance is: " << vectorMax(dif) << endl << "Avrage of your distance is: " << vectorAvr(dif) << endl;
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you run through a debugger which part gives the error?

Comment: `v[v.size()];` is by definition an out of bounds access - use either `v[v.size() - 1];` or `v.back();`

Comment: If you want the last element in a vector, use vector.back().  Second, your functions cannot work if they are fed empty vectors.  You have out of bounds access violations, along with a divide by zero error in the function that computes the average.  You need to check for the vector being empty before assuming it has at least one value.